# How to fill in blank (integer) places with zero in C?

Tags: c, time, formatting, printf, string-formatting

I want to add a leading zero in a C integer. I am making a clock. Here is the code I have so far:

```
int main(){

    while (1){
    time_t present;
    time(&present);
    struct tm *myTime =  localtime(&present);
    printf("%2d:%2d:%2d\n", myTime->tm_hour,myTime->tm_min, myTime->tm_sec);
    sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the current output:

```
11:30: 0
11:30: 1
11:30: 2
11:30: 3
11:30: 4
11:30: 5
11:30: 6
11:30: 7
11:30: 8
11:30: 9
11:30:10
```

Here is the output I want:

```
11:30:00
11:30:01
11:30:02
//and so on...
```

Comment: Read up on `printf()` in your favorite documentation source - man page, cppreference, etc.

Comment: Use `%02d` format

Comment: As explained on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/, '%2d' means that the length is 2, and in order to get to 2, a blank should be added. However if you put '%02d' (as mentioned in the answer), you specifically mention that a zero character must be used instead of a blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill a `0` betwen the `%` and the length modifier, here `2`, at each format specifier in the `printf()` call:

```
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", myTime->tm_hour,myTime->tm_min, myTime->tm_sec);
         |    |    |
        here here here
```